# Lollipop android lock screen widget

Tags: android, widget

Are there any changes made to lock screen widgets in lollipop. Though official documents explicitly shows no changes but ,http://www.extremetech.com/computing/192112-android-5-0-lollipop-all-details-and-features-of-googles-sweetest-treat-yet says lock screen widgets are gone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lock screen widgets do not exist in either of the Android Developer Preview builds of Android 5.0 so they are effectively gone. However, [WIDGET_CATEGORY_KEYGUARD](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#WIDGET_CATEGORY_KEYGUARD) has not yet been deprecated. Whether this is an oversight or not is anyone's guess. There does not appear to be any gesture, area, or anything else (such as anything in the Settings app) in the Android 5.0 builds so far that would indicate support for lock screen widgets.

It appears the main case for lock screen widgets is suggested to be handled by notifications, similar to how [music controls have changed](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#BehaviorMediaControl) - the old `RemoteControlClient` based controls used to take up the same place as lock screen widgets but have been completely deprecated.

Comment: Official factory images/OTAs to Lollipop show that lock screen widgets are not accessible in any way on Android 5.0 devices.

Comment: Ok, can I confirm that by no means I can remove and insert the clock widget in lock screen ?

Comment: No, with stock Android 5.0 there is no way to change the clock on the lock screen (certainly if you built your own entire ROM, you might be able to change it...)

Comment: The [Adenda SDK](http://adendamedia.com) effectively extends the Android libraries to let you add custom lock screen behavior to your app

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80428&can=1&q=widget%20lockscreen&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Yes, widgets are not there is lollipop lock screen . Issue has been raised with android bug tracker in the above link. If possible star this bug for speedy process.Lets hope we get it back.

Answer (score 1):

Direct from Google:

I spoke directly with a Google Engineer today.
She mentioned that the feature was added in API 4.2 and removed as of API 5.0

Hope this helps!

Comment: Lol at your username> IOS Dev ahahha

Comment: Yeah, since joining Stack Overflow, I've expanded the platforms I develop and architect for (As well as potential job prospects )  :). Are you still laughing? ;-)